# How can I combine Google's Global Site Tag with Subresource Integrity?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm implementing global tracking on my site following the [steps described by Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/). But I want to also keep my `Subresource Integrity` (SRI) up to date. So I ran the following command to find the integrity hash for `gtag.js`.

```
> curl -s https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js |\
  openssl dgst -sha384 -binary |\
  openssl base64 -A
```

Adding this as the integrity attribute to the `script` tag with the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute, causes the browser to fail loading the gtag script. Reason:

> Subresource Integrity: The resource 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js' has an integrity attribute, but the resource requires the request to be CORS enabled to check the integrity, and it is not. The resource has been blocked because the integrity cannot be enforced.

Apparent reason is the `access-control-allow-origin` header which google returns and only allows the same-host origin.

Does anyone know if there is a different host for this script? Is there another way to adopt gtag in your site?

Comment: Did you find an answer/solution to this elsewhere?

Comment: No I haven’t. I’ve also tried to ask Google through forum and feedback, but no response.

Answer (score 6):

The only workaround for this may be to simply fetch the resource, store it on the same server, and then set your own `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

This is a bit silly - because not only does it reduce the value of distributing the resource via CDN, it effectively makes the SRI pointless (because you're working with a static local copy, not a remote one the warrants reducing the risk of manipulation by verifying it with SRI).

This will also only work as long as the resource remains static. But since SRI *depends* on the resource being static (so that the hash will match), any change to the resource on the server would result in SRI enforcement causing the resource to fail anyway.

So it may be no more fragile than using SRI in the first place (unless you're generating the checksum of the resource on the fly ... at which point there's less of a point in using SRI in the first place).

UPDATE 2020-09-22: It looks like the issue [may have been resolved](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/15985818?hl=en) on the Google side in April 2020.

Comment: Seems still not resolved. I'm struggling with it now. All my other js resources work fine with SRI but not googletagmanager.

Comment: I am confused. SRI depends on fix hashes and only makes sense if it is really fix. But when I am checking https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx in srihash.org, the hash changes every few minutes. So, is there even a safe solution?